# mySQL space before field value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to put a space in if the value is not blank but it seems to only output a number when i run the query?

```
CONCAT(address, IF(address2 = '', '', ' ' & address2), ' ', city, ', ', state, ' ', zip) AS theAddress
```

The query output for the above is:

```
1234 N. Shore Ave.0 Burbank, CA 41577
```

The output should look like this:

```
1234 N. Shore Ave. Apartment 223 Burbank, CA 41577
```

What would i be doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CONCAT(address, IF(address2 = '', '', CONCAT(' ', address2)), ' ', city, ', ', state, ' ', zip) AS theAddress
```

I think what your code is doing is a Logical AND between a space and address2

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be another `concat` not `&`

```
CONCAT(address, IF(address2 = '', '', CONCAT(' ',  address2)), ' ', city, ', ', state, ' ', zip) AS theAddress
                                         ^ here
```

`' ' & address2` returns 0 and 1 (true or false)

Comment: oh i overlooked it, it should be another `concat` :)